# SAS: Exporting Data Subsets to Separate Workbook Tabs in Excel

Tags: sas, export, export-to-excel

**Question:** How can I export subsets of a data set to individual tabs of an Excel workbook (preferably .xlsx) without running `PROC EXPORT` several times?

---

**My Solution**

The data set contains 15 indicators.  Unfortunately, the indicators do not have names which can be indexed.  This means I cannot put the export procedure into a macro which loops over a counter 15 times and appends the name with the index.  The indicators are (not really) things like "car", "truck", "bicycle", "dinosaur", etc.

The solution I came up with was like this:

```
proc export data = data_set 
                (where = (indicator = "car"))
            outfile = "c:\workbook.xlsx"
            dbms = xlsx replace;
            sheet = car;
run;

...

proc export data = data_set 
                (where = (indicator = "dinosaur"))
            outfile = "c:\workbook.xlsx"
            dbms = xlsx replace;
            sheet = dinosaur;
run;
```

However, this is obviously inefficient and begs for some sort of automation.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have? If 9.4 ODS Excel can be used automatically, otherwise use Tagsets but it will create an xml not xlsx file.

Comment: I am using SAS 9.4.  I am not sure what other products or maintenance updates I have.  How would I check on that?  And thank you for asking, this is information I should remember to provide when asking questions.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `libname` facility, which is what `proc export` uses in the background usually.

```
libname myexcel xlsx "c:\outwhatever\myfile.xlsx";  *can use XLSX if 9.4+ or EXCEL if earlier;
```

That gives you a regular libname just as if it were a SAS libname, and you can write to it like so:

```
data myexcel.sheetname;
  set whatever;
run;
```

Or use `PROC COPY`  or similar.

There are other options (using `OLEDB` or similar, for example), but `libname` is simplest.  See [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63181/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1wvmggexroxgyn17rp61jml3cvn.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SAS 9.4 ODS Excel is quite simple and nice, set the sheet_interval option to bygroup and add a prefix for the sheet name.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by age;
run;

ods excel file='/folders/myfolders/sample.xlsx' options (sheet_interval='bygroup' sheet_label='Age');

proc print data=class noobs label;
by age;
run;

ods excel close;
```